# Sort Complex Array of Arrays by value within

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, undefined, sorting

I have an array of arrays in javascript set up within an object that I'm storing with local storage. It's high scores for a Phonegap game in the format `{'0':[[score,time],[score,time]}` where 0 is the category.  I'm able to see the scores using `a[1][0]`. I want to sort with the high scores first.

```
var c={'0':[[100,11],[150,12]};
c.sort(function(){
    x=a[0];
    y=b[0];
    return y-x;
}
```

However, b[0] always gives an undefined error.

I'm new to Javascript and making this is my first major test as a learning experience. Though I've looked at a number of examples on stackoverflow still can't figured this one out.

Comment: Where/how are `a` and `b` defined?

Comment: The examples you've given are syntactically incorrect:  this is missing a square bracket:  `{'0':[[score,time],[score,time]}`

Comment: @Jeff a and b are the default .sort parameters. So a[0] should be the first item in the array?

Comment: @Matt thanks! I was re-typing for the post and missed that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare the parameters to the comparator function.

```
c.sort(function(){
```

should be

```
c.sort(function(a, b){
```

and you need to call `sort` on an array as "am not i am" points out so

```
var c={'0':[[100,11],[150,12]]};
c[0].sort(function(a, b){
    var x=a[0];
    var y=b[0];
    return y-x;
});
```

leaves `c` in the following state:

```
{
  "0": [
    [150, 12],
    [100, 11]
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the quick and awesome response! I had been looking at examples here and on Google for days... I didn't realize I had to have the parameters `(a,b)` in the function. Just added the code and my scores are in the right order finally!

Answer (score 0):

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

    for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
        arr[x] = arr[x].sort(function(a,b){
            return b - a;
        });
    }

    return arr;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [ [11, 5, 6, 3, 10], [22,55,33,66,11,00], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 999]];

_.eachRight(myArray, function(value) {
  var descending = _.sortBy(value).reverse();
  console.log(descending);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```