# How to sort Array of Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to sort an array like the one below based on the difference between "over" "under" odds of a match, so the most balanced outcome goes to the first row of the main array!

```
var object = [
        [{"0.5": { "over": 1.2, "under": 3.8 }}], //difference 2.6
        [{"1.5": { "over": 1.5, "under": 2.8 }}], //difference 1.3
        [{"2.5": { "over": 1.9, "under": 2.0 }}], //difference 0.1
        [{"2.5": { "over": 2.2, "under": 1.8 }}], //difference 0.4
    ];
```

Like this

```
var object = [
    [{ "2.5": { "over": 1.9, "under": 2.0 } }], //difference 0.1
    [{ "2.5": { "over": 2.2, "under": 1.8 } }], //difference 0.4
    [{ "1.5": { "over": 1.5, "under": 2.8 } }], //difference 1.3
    [{ "0.5": { "over": 1.2, "under": 3.8 } }], //difference 2.6
];
```

I have read this post but it's not of any help in my case

[Sort Complex Array of Arrays by value within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316119/sort-complex-array-of-arrays-by-value-within)

I just solved it. Thanks guys!

```
var obj = [{ value: 0.5, over: 1.2, under: 3.8 },
        { value: 1.5, over: 1.5, under: 3.2 },
        { value: 2.5, over: 1.8, under: 2.5 },
        { value: 3.5, over: 1.9, under: 1.9 },
        { value: 3.5, over: 2.5, under: 1.75 }];



obj.sort(function(a,b) { 
    return Math.min(Math.abs(parseFloat(b.over) - parseFloat(a.under)));
    });
```

Comment: How is it not of any help? It shows you how you can sort an array by passing a custom compare callback function. All you need to do is sort your main array, and compare two items in it in your callback.

Comment: You have too many arrays there, you don't need the nested arrays. If you just use a colleciton you can try Underscore's `sortBy`

Comment: `function(a,b) {return Math.abs(a.over-a.under) - Math.abs(b.over-a.under);}`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: That would work if OP didn't have nested everything. I would look into fixing the source where this is coming from, so I get a decent data-structure to work with.

Comment: @elclanrs Oh yeah. I guess `a[0].over` et al. but yeah, over-nested.

Comment: It's not the same with the example given above. As a starter I need the sorting descending. I'm trying but not accomplishing anything.

Comment: Your data structure looks messed up, ideally you'd want something like `[{value:2.5, over:1.9, under:2.0},...}]`. That would be much easier to maintain and work with. Where's the data coming from? Why not start fixing the problem there?

Comment: I simulated the data to be similar with the example found in the answer for a question mentioned above. I will definitely use this structure! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, another problem! My data are not limited to four rows, they are received via ajax request and may contain 0 - unknown number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object.sort(function(x,y){
    var xx,yy,x1,y1;
    for(var i in x[0]){xx=x[0][i];break;}
    for(var i in y[0]){yy=y[0][i];break;}
    x1=Math.abs(xx.over-xx.under);
    y1=Math.abs(yy.over-yy.under);
    return x1===y1?0:x1>y1?1:-1;
});
```

Comment: Thank's CrossUI, it's perfect. A bit disappointed with the quickdownvoters here though. I don't think at all this could be solved with the example mentioned above. Besides I offered it myself, which means I had done the research, proved it and it didn't work. Thanks Again CrossUi!