# Sort javascript object with array as value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have a Javascript Object in the format `key:pair` where the `pair` is an array containing 2 timestamp values. I would like to sort this object so that the elements with the lowest numbers (earliest times) are displayed first.

Here is an example of the object: `{"21_2":[1409158800,1409160000],"20_1":[1409148000,1409149200],"56_1":[1409149800,1409151600]}`

So in this case, I would want the final sorted object to read:

`{"20_1":[1409148000,1409149200],"56_1":[1409149800,1409151600],"21_2":[1409158800,1409160000]}`

Obviously the `sort()` function will come into play here for the arrays, but how do I access those values inside the object? Note the object `key` isn't actually an integer because of the underscore.

I have found this: [Sort Complex Array of Arrays by value within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316119/sort-complex-array-of-arrays-by-value-within) but haven't been able to apply it to my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't sort JavaScript Objects. Only arrays can be sorted.

Comment: That aside, what are you trying to do? This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890807/iterate-over-a-javascript-associative-array-in-sorted-order

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Comment: @Cerbrus we can't put that aside, the question goes to an end here **You can't sort JavaScript Objects**, *Until you change that to array*

Comment: What is the end goal of "sorting" this object? By saying "I want the final sorted object to read" you are basically saying you want to modify the `toString()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the structure of your data like this:

```
var myArray = [{
        "id" : "21_2" // id or whatever these are
        "timeStamps" : [1409158800,1409160000]
    }, {
        "id" : "20_1"
        "timeStamps" : [1409148000,1409149200]
    }];
```

Then you could sort it by the regular array sort:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b){
    // however you want to compare them:
    return a.timeStamps[0] - b.timeStamps[0]; 
});
```